# TaskCompletionSource<T> for Silverlight?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

just searching for a way to use the TaskCompletionSource class in Silverlight.

So first off, will it be available in Silverlight ver 5?

Second, are Reactive Extensions a good way to go?

Third, I came across PowerThreading from Jeffery Richter.  Is this still a good way to go with Silverlight?

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2008/11/05/new-version-of-power-threading-library-dated-october-30-2008.aspx

there's a port here (which I'm trying... assuming that pushing Silverlight 5 RC to a client even for testing is probably a bad thing)

http://www.damonpayne.com/post/2011/02/13/Binary-Drop-For-the-Task-Parallel-Library-for-Silverlight.aspx

http://www.perreira.net/matthieu/?page_id=172  (in French)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, TaskCompletionSource<T>, as well as the whole Task Parallel Library, [is available in Silverlight 5](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2011/09/silverlight-5-rc-using-task-parallel.html).

Reactive Extensions are great, really a higher level way of thinking about events and async operations. Definitely recommended for use in .NET, Silverlight, and JavaScript projects.

I don't recommend Richter's PowerThreading library now; with the TPL making its way into SL 5, there's little use for his library, IMO.